# How to define a variable after checking variable already defined or not in robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I'm new to robot framework.
I have a robot frame work code which I run using command

```
robot --variable color:red myrobo.robot
```

Here I'm passing variable `${color}` as command line argument.
In robot code I want to check whether the variable color is defined or not.
The purpose is if I ran robot code like

```
robot myrobo.robot
```

I should have a default value for `${color}`.
If I didn't pass any command line argument I want `${color} = 'yellow'`
If I pass command line argument as color:red I should have `${color} = 'red'.`

How to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

You can define the variable in the [variable table](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variable-table) with a default value.

```
*** Variables ***
${color}         yellow

*** Test Cases ***
```

This value will be overwritten with the command line argument,

```
robot --variable color:red myrobo.robot
```

or it will hold its default value when the command line argument is not used.

```
robot myrobo.robot
```